# add li to middle of the ul (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

How one can add li to middle of the ul.

For example if i have list like this:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

And i want to add addiion li (`<li>new</li>`) after 3rd list?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted an answer to this question yet?

Answer (score 31):

```
var middle = Math.ceil($("#myUL li").length / 2);
$("#myUL li:nth-child(" + middle + ")").after('<li>Item New</li>');
```

Comment: middle should have been Math.ceil($("#myUL").children("li").length / 2); as we might encounter nested lists. 2 cents

Answer (score 11):

Try this out:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').after('<li>new</li>');
```

Comment: this assums a fixed number of li items... better use Aquino solution. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul li:eq(2)').after(`<li>new</li>`)
```

Use ' or " within braces I have used ` since it was getting formatted as html.